# Second order differential equation to two equations of first order

Tags: differential-equations, homework

Here is a differential equation

```
x''[t] - eps (a^2 - x[t]^2) x'[t] + w^2*x[t] == 0
```

boundary conditions are

```
x[0]=0,
v[0]=0.001
```

i want to substitute x'[t] to v[t] and then NDSolve the equation to respect of x and v.

Right now my code looks like this

```
NDSolve[{
  x''[t] - eps (a^2 - x[t]^2) x'[t] + w^2*x[t] == 0 /. {x'[t] -> v[t], x''[t] -> v'[t]}
  x[0] == 0,
  v[0] == 0.001},
 {x[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

and it obviously doesnt work. I suppose that ./ substitution isn't enough and I need to make more equations but i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

First, when you want to solve for two variables,x and v, you need two equations. Add  x'[t] == v[t]  .

Second, with NDSolve, all parameters, w,a,eps, have to be given numerical values.

```
ndsol[w_, a_, eps_] := 
   NDSolve[{x''[t] - eps (a^2 - x[t]^2) x'[t] + w^2*x[t] == 
      0 /. {x'[t] -> v[t], x''[t] -> v'[t]}, x'[t] == v[t], x[0] == 0, 
      v[0] == 0.001}, {x, v}, {t, 0, 10}]

Plot[Evaluate[v[t] /. ndsol[3, 2, -3]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

And exactly the same

```
Plot[Evaluate[x'[t] /. ndsol[3, 2, -3]], {t, 0, 10}]
```